# Issue with bash suffixs output into Console

Tags: bash

Hello i am currently having issues with my bash script where i am trying to read and output a file with suffixs based on user choices. choices = what suffixs get applied.

CODE:

```
echo 'Input 1, 2, 3 or 4'

read VarChoice

if [[ $VarChoice == "1" ]]
    then nl -bt Test.txt

elif [[ $VarChoice == "2" ]]
    then cat -n Test.txt

elif [[ $VarChoice == "3" ]]
    then  sed 's/$/$/' Test.txt

elif [[ $VarChoice == "4" ]]
    then cat -n .bashrc && sed 's/$/$/' Test.txt
    fi

echo 'press any button to end the script'
read
```

When i run each suffix command in terminal i get the output screen of the suffix being applied but when i use the command within the bash script i do not get the output.

Is this normal or am i doing somthing wrong ?

thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: What do you get instead? Do *any* of the options work?

Comment: No i get nothing it just moves onto the next line of code / ends the script.

Comment: Are you using it in a `while read` loop?

Comment: No but it is after the end of a loop

Comment: That sounds like `$VarChoice` isn't matching any of the comparisons. Try putting `set -x` before this section, and see what the shell thinks is happening.

Comment: The Output was
++ [[ ends == \n\o\n\e\b\l\a\c\k ]]
++ [[ ends == \N\u\m\b\e\r ]]
++ [[ ends == \e\n\d\s ]]
++ sed 's/$/$/' .bashrc
sed: can't read .bashrc: No such file or directory

Comment: From the commandline you are in your home directory. When you start the script, you are in another directory or the script moves you to another place `cd somedir`.

Comment: it starts me in / i assume. i would think that means my problem is that i need to start the script in the directory where the target file is.